# python logic/code to skip few lines by comparing string

Tags: python

i have one file and contain some data

```
 Net Name:  VDD
 Pin Name:  VDD
 Instance Name:  ld_slice_logic_wrap_inst/ld_slice_logic_top_inst/ld_clk_gen_top_inst/ld_wdqs_clk_gen

 Layer/Via#  PGResistor  Resistance(cumulative) Ohm  Voltage_Drop(cumulative) V  Length 
 VSRC       N 0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 3.7865e-03 3.7865e-03  0  144.43150,550.00000   
 AP         N 1.0000e-06 1.0000e-06 0.0000e+00 3.7865e-03  0.000100000001  144.43150,550
 AP         N 3.1474e-03 3.1484e-03 5.6028e-06 3.7921e-03  6.8432998  144.43200,550.0000
 AP         N 1.0000e-06 3.1494e-03 0.0000e+00 3.7921e-03  0.000200000003  144.43200,543
 AP         N 1.9433e-03 5.0927e-03 1.1802e-05 3.8039e-03  4.1663999  144.43200,543.1565
 AP         N 2.5653e-03 7.6580e-03 1.7583e-05 3.8215e-03  5.5001001  144.43200,538.9900
 AP         N 1.0137e-02 1.7795e-02 7.0572e-05 3.8921e-03  8.851  144.43200,533.49000   
 AP         N 2.1164e-02 3.8959e-02 1.5050e-04 4.0426e-03  16.0295  144.43200,524.63900 
 AP         N 9.9838e-07 3.8960e-02 0.0000e+00 4.0426e-03  0.054  128.40250,524.63900   
 RV         N 3.3405e-02 7.2365e-02 2.3925e-04 4.2818e-03  2.7  128.40250,524.69300   
 M15        N 9.9838e-07 7.2366e-02 0.0000e+00 4.2818e-03  0.6985  128.40250,524.69300  
 M15        N 1.0580e-01 1.7817e-01 4.3488e-04 4.7167e-03  14.947  127.70400,524.69300  
 VIA14      N 8.8155e-03 1.8698e-01 5.1737e-05 4.7684e-03  0.324  127.70400,539.64000   
 M14        N 3.5033e-02 2.2201e-01 1.1855e-04 4.8870e-03  4.96  127.70400,539.64000   
 M14        N 1.6951e-01 3.9153e-01 1.3857e-03 6.2727e-03  24  132.66400,539.64000   
 M9         N 9.5367e-07 6.2670e+00 0.0000e+00 7.4605e-03  0.26  187.49200,516.86300 
      
 Layer/Via  Resistance(Ohm)  Voltage_Drop(V)  R_Cumulative(Ohm)  Vdrop_Cummulative(V) 
 VSRC        0.0000e+00  3.7865e-03  0.0000e+00  3.7865e-03 
 AP          3.8960e-02  2.5606e-04  3.8960e-02  4.0426e-03 
 RV          3.3405e-02  2.3925e-04  7.2365e-02  4.2818e-03 
 M15         1.0580e-01  4.3488e-04  1.7817e-01  4.7167e-03 
 VIA14       8.8155e-03  5.1737e-05  1.8698e-01  4.7684e-03 
 M9          2.2392e+00  5.8532e-05  6.2670e+00  7.4605e-03 

 Net Name:  VSS
 Pin Name:  VSS
 Instance Name:  ld_slice_logic_wrap_inst/ld_slice_logic_top_inst/ld_clk_gen_top_inst/ld_wdqs_clk_gen

 Layer/Via#  PGResistor  Resistance(cumulative) Ohm  Voltage_Drop(cumulative) V  Length 
 VSRC       N 0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 3.7865e-03 3.7865e-03  0  144.43150,550.00000   
 AP         N 1.0000e-06 1.0000e-06 0.0000e+00 3.7865e-03  0.000100000001  144.43150,550
 AP         N 3.1474e-03 3.1484e-03 5.6028e-06 3.7921e-03  6.8432998  144.43200,550.0000
 AP         N 1.0000e-06 3.1494e-03 0.0000e+00 3.7921e-03  0.000200000003  144.43200,543
 AP         N 1.9433e-03 5.0927e-03 1.1802e-05 3.8039e-03  4.1663999  144.43200,543.1565
 AP         N 2.5653e-03 7.6580e-03 1.7583e-05 3.8215e-03  5.5001001  144.43200,538.9900
 AP         N 1.0137e-02 1.7795e-02 7.0572e-05 3.8921e-03  8.851  144.43200,533.49000   
 AP         N 2.1164e-02 3.8959e-02 1.5050e-04 4.0426e-03  16.0295  144.43200,524.63900 
 AP         N 9.9838e-07 3.8960e-02 0.0000e+00 4.0426e-03  0.054  128.40250,524.63900   
 RV         N 3.3405e-02 7.2365e-02 2.3925e-04 4.2818e-03  2.7  128.40250,524.69300   
 M15        N 9.9838e-07 7.2366e-02 0.0000e+00 4.2818e-03  0.6985  128.40250,524.69300  
 M15        N 1.0580e-01 1.7817e-01 4.3488e-04 4.7167e-03  14.947  127.70400,524.69300  
 VIA14      N 8.8155e-03 1.8698e-01 5.1737e-05 4.7684e-03  0.324  127.70400,539.64000   
 M14        N 3.5033e-02 2.2201e-01 1.1855e-04 4.8870e-03  4.96  127.70400,539.64000   
 M14        N 1.6951e-01 3.9153e-01 1.3857e-03 6.2727e-03  24  132.66400,539.64000   
 M9         N 9.5367e-07 6.2670e+00 0.0000e+00 7.4605e-03  0.26  187.49200,516.86300 
      
 Layer/Via  Resistance(Ohm)  Voltage_Drop(V)  R_Cumulative(Ohm)  Vdrop_Cummulative(V) 
 VSRC        0.0000e+00  3.7865e-03  0.0000e+00  3.7865e-03 
 AP          3.8960e-02  2.5606e-04  3.8960e-02  4.0426e-03 
 RV          3.3405e-02  2.3925e-04  7.2365e-02  4.2818e-03 
 M15         1.0580e-01  4.3488e-04  1.7817e-01  4.7167e-03 
 VIA14       8.8155e-03  5.1737e-05  1.8698e-01  4.7684e-03 
 M9          2.2392e+00  5.8532e-05  6.2670e+00  7.4655e-03
```

the file data will repeate with **Net Name** and **Pin Name** as **VDDA,VSS,VSSA....**

I Want to skip the **DATA** between **Layer/Via#** and **Layer/Via** and i want to consider only **M9** data after the Layer/Via with the last value **" eg: 7.4605e-03 "**

The logic i tried

```
def readPinFile(filename): 

    result = None
    with open(filename, "r") as file:   

        result = {}
        lastPin = None        
        for line in file:
            lines = line.strip()
            
            if lines[:3] == "Net": 
                Net_Name = lines.split(" ")[-1]               
                result[lines] = {"Pin_Name": None, "M9": None}
            
            if lines[:3] == "Pin":
                result[lines]["Pin_Name"] = lines.split(" ")[1]
               
            if lines[:2] == "M9":
                result[Net_Name]["M9"] = lines.split(" ")[-1]

    return result
 
readPinFile("inst_1.txt")
```

Expected output

```
{'Pin_Name': 'VDD', 'Net_Name': 'VSS', 'M9': '7.4605e-03'}
{'Pin_Name': 'VSS', 'Net_Name': 'VSS', 'M9': '7.4655e-03'}
```

after reaching this stage I stared confused and became blank to continue.
can anyone please guide me to come out of this.

Comment: Could you provide the expected output too ?

Comment: How many sections does your file have? Are you only interested in skipping the first section ?

Comment: @S.B actually the 350+ sections are there, every time I want to skip 1st portion and write data on the variable.

Answer (score 0):

For `net_name` and `pin_name`, you don't need to put an if-statement in every iteration. File object is an iterator so you can just call `next` on them.

I assumed you wanted to skip just the first section, so I used a flag to skip lines between two `"Layer/Via"`:

```py
def read_pin_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        # get infromation from fist two lines
        net_name = next(f).strip().rsplit(maxsplit=1)[1]
        pin_name = next(f).strip().rsplit(maxsplit=1)[1]

        # This loop is for skipping that secction
        flag_count = 0
        for line in f:
            if line.strip().startswith("Layer/Via"):
                flag_count += 1
            if flag_count == 2:
                # We're on section two.
                break

        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line.startswith("M9"):
                return {
                    "Pin_Name": pin_name,
                    "Net_Name": net_name,
                    "M9": line.rsplit(maxsplit=1)[1],
                }

print(read_pin_file("inst_1.txt"))
```

output:

```
{'Pin_Name': 'VDD', 'Net_Name': 'VDD', 'M9': '7.4605e-03'}
```

Comment: Line number 4&5 gets an error as the "list index out of range".     
can you explain this:encoding="utf-8" as well as line numbers 4&5

Comment: @SanthoshNayakD. You get exception because I assumed `Net Name:  VDD` line and `Pin Name:  VDD` line appears on line 1 and 2 respectively. This is what your text file indicates. Since they contain at least two words and you can get index 1 from the result of split.

Comment: @SanthoshNayakD. `encoding="utf-8"` is not crucial here, I just added it as a habit. It tells Python in which encoding it should parse the file.

Comment: @SanthoshNayakD. `next()` gives you the next line, `rsplit`, splits the line from the right.

Comment: what are the things I want to change if the same data occurs multiple times?